# requirejs loading same module twice

Tags: javascript, requirejs, singleton

I'm using the single-page app template from https://github.com/volojs/create-template

I tried to make a simple example below.

#### Problem

`ModuleA.js` is being loaded twice, once directly from `main.js` and again from `simulator.js` which depends also on that module. This is causing two different references to an object (which I thought would only be one, like a singleton). I thought requirejs would not load the same module twice. Being (relatively) new to JavaScript I realize this may be naivete on my part. I'm trying to follow the template.

Here's a simplified version that demonstrates the problem:

#### www/index.html

```
<head>
...
    <script data-main="app" src="lib/require.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

#### www/app.js

```
// For any third party dependencies, like jQuery, place them in the lib folder.
// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except for 'app' ones, which are in a sibling
// directory.

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start loading the main app file. Put all of
// your application logic in there.
requirejs(['app/main']);
```

#### www/app/main.js

```
define(function (require) {
    var simulator = require('./simulator.js');
    var ModuleA = require('./ModuleA.js');

    ModuleA.init();
    ModuleA.displayList();
    ModuleA.update("joe", 99);
    ModuleA.displayList();

    simulator.start(); // should display the same list
});
```

#### www/app/ModuleA.js

```
define(function () {
    var theList = {};
    console.log("loading ModuleA");
    return {
        displayList: function () {
            console.log(Object.keys(theList));
        },
        init : function () {
            theList["fred"] = 10;
        },
        update : function (k, v) {
            theList[k] = v;
        }
    }
});
```

#### www/app/simulator.js

```
define(["./ModuleA"], function (ModuleA) {
  return {
    start: function () {
      ModuleA.displayList();
    }
  };
});
```

#### console output:

```
loading ModuleA
loading ModuleA
["fred"]
["fred", "joe"]
[]
```

The empty `[]` displayed on the last line is (likely) the second copy of the list due to the second loading of `ModuleA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the module references are not consistent. In main.js it requires `./ModuleA.js` whereas in simulator.js it defines `./ModuleA` (without the `.js` filetype).

Making those references identical corrects the behavior such that the module is only loaded once.

I guess I mixed the styles because of the many examples on the web. It kind of seems like a bug that it works this way, but maybe it's a feature?

Comment: yes, module references are actually IDs, which requireJs assumes one id for one module. They explained it a bit here http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Comment: Not only that: The way require.js stores module IDs are case sensitive... even though it will load the correct module regardless of case. Ask me, I just spent two hours trying to figure out why a script called TSBase was loading twice (once as data-main and once from a circular require call in something it loaded). Turns out TSBase could be found and loaded even if you call it TSbase, but it was considered a different module because of the lowercase 'b'. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share an instantiated singleton object using requireJS, you can do something like this for ModuleA:

```
define(function () {
  console.log("loading ModuleA");
  function myList(){
    this.theList = {}
  } 
  myList.prototype.displayList = function () { 
      console.log(Object.keys(this.theList));
  } 
  myList.prototype.init = function () { 
      this.theList["fred"] = 10;
  } 
  myList.prototype.update = function (k, v) { 
      this.theList[k] = v;
  } 
  return new myList();
});
```